# How to customize button css in react-admin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react-admin, and how to customize react admin buttons?
In my scenario I have a list also in create, edit, and export button there and I don't know which is the best way to change button css in react-admin. Can anyone solve this?

By default I have button like above mentioned, so I need to add css for this two buttons.

[image]

Here is my sample code

```
// style list
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  userCard: {
    padding: "20px",
    borderRadius: "12px",
  },
  btn_edit: {
    background: "#5E35B1",
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: "10px",
  },

  mainList: {
    boxShadow: "none !important",
    borderRadius: "0px",
  },
  listCreateIcon: {
    padding: "0px !important",
  },
}));
```

```
//main
export const UserList = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.userCard}>
      <List
        {...props}
        pagination={null}
        perPage={9999}
        className={classes.mainList}
      >
        <Datagrid className={classes.listCard}>
          <TextField source="username" />
          <BooleanField source="enabled" />
          <ReferenceArrayField reference="_roles" source="roles">
            <SingleFieldList>
              <ChipField source="name" />
            </SingleFieldList>
          </ReferenceArrayField>
          <EditButton className={classes.btn_edit} />
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    </Card>
  );
};

export const UserCreate = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Create {...props} className={classes.listCreateIcon}>
      <SimpleForm style={{ padding: "0px !important" }}>
        <TextInput source="username" />
        <TextInput type="password" source="password" />
        <ReferenceArrayInput source="roles" reference="_roles" allowEmpty>
          <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceArrayInput>
        <BooleanInput source="enabled" defaultValue={true} />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
export const UserEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <TextField source="username" />
      <ReferenceArrayInput source="roles" reference="_roles">
        <SelectArrayInput optionText="name" />
      </ReferenceArrayInput>
      <BooleanInput source="enabled" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Where is your problem? Just add `backgroundColor` (instead of `background`) and `borderRadius` to `btnEdit`,

Comment: @ulou actually, i don't know where i need to write classes for applying css in create and export buttons shown in above. there is no problem with editBtn. my problem is "applying css for Create and Export button"

Comment: The css is working as a json in useStyle, So you need to add that inside of `useStyles`. It is available to create any class, and styles.

Comment: @Expressd3v But where shoud i add ```className={classes.something}``` ? here there is no "Create and Export" buttons element. it is a prebuilt in react-admin right.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
btn_create: {   
    display: "inline-flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    gridGap: 4,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "transparent",
    fontSize: 16, 
    color: "blue" // the text color you want
    // if you are using the svg icon
    svg : {
       width: 16,
       height: 16,
       path: {
           fill : "blue" //color code of icon 
       }
    }
  },
btn_group: {
    display:"flex",
    gridGap: "16px",
    alignItems: "Center",
}
```

on Component

```
<div className={classes.btn_group}>
    <EditButton className={classes.btn_create} />
    <EditButton className={classes.btn_create} />
</div>
```

PS. If the icon is font icon, you may not use the svg styling.

Comment: thats my custom button. its working fine.  i need to change css with above mentioned ```Create``` and ```Export``` buttons